# How to get the value from last row in while loop?

Tags: php

I wonder why while loop does not overwrite the **$kid** value?

```
$lastrow = //another mysql query to get the id of last row.

    $kid = 0;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT kid.......

    while(list($kid) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    ...
    }

    echo $kid;

if ($lastrow != $kid) echo "<a href="/show-more.php">show more results</a>";
```

For some reason after while loop $kid is "" - empty and the loop does not overwrite this value.

Comment: do you increment $kid inside the loop?

Comment: whats happening in list( $kid )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$kid = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT kid.......

while(list($temp_kid) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $kid = $temp_kid;
}

echo $kid;
```

Try this...

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted … it's obviously a valid solution (although it could use some additional explanation)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop ends when the condition first is falsy (0). This means, that `$kid` will always have a value that evaluates to false after the loop.

Something along the following lines should work:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $kid = $row['kid'];
}
```

Although I'm not sure if you are taking the right way to solve your problem. What are you trying to accomplish? I assume it would make more sense to only select a single row from the database.